# Celery tasks failing randomly

Tags: django, celery, celery-task

I have a Celery `shared_task`, which is getting called from my view when the user initiates a request on that view. Due to some weird reason, the tasks are not getting registered at random times.

What am I missing? Is this behavior expected?

`views.py`

```
from rpc.components.tasks import run_async

@csrf_exempt
def run(request):
    try:    
        run_async.delay(request)
        # return response

    except Exception as e:
        # return error response
```

`tasks.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def run_async(request):
    #do some stuff
    return True
```

Comment: Why do you believe the "tasks are not getting registered at random times"?

Comment: Do you see the tasks get registered with celery when you start up the worker?

Comment: @user2097159 I'm tailing the logs, and I cannot see the tasks at random times.

Comment: @Brandon Well, I'm importing the tasks in the __init__.py of the project root. So I presume the tasks are getting registered indeed.

Comment: Importing tasks in your Python code doesn't mean they're being picked up by Celery. What does: `celery -A your_app worker -l info` tell you?

Comment: :) Yes, the task is getting registered.

Comment: is there perhaps something in the task that's failing and preventing a return?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71823/discussion-between-theg33k-and-brandon).

Comment: I had this problem once, it turned out I had extra celery workers online that I forgot about, and wasn't seeing their logs.

Comment: @Gourneau I just have one celery worker running. Any other reasons?